# How to randomly print asterisk on a grid using user input

Tags: java

**Project objective:** Take user input. The asterisk are randomly placed and can only have one per section.

Error : can't print asterisk. I have tried `System.out.println('*');` but then the grid becomes destroyed.I also am not sure how to set it to match user input to randomly place the asterisk.

What Output should look like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQXvv.jpg

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Random;

    public class project {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int rows = 0;
        while (rows < 1 || rows > 9) {
            System.out.println("rows? ");
            rows = sc.nextInt();
        }
        int columns = 0;
        while (columns < 1 || columns > 9) {
            System.out.println(" columns?");
            columns = sc.nextInt();
            int length = 0;
            System.out.println("side length?");
            length = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.print("  " + "|");
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                System.out.print("   " + j);
            }
            System.out.println();
            for (int j = 0; j <= columns; j++) {
                System.out.print("----");
            }
            System.out.println();
            int[][] board = new int[rows][columns];
            Random rand = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                System.out.print(i + "  |");
                for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                    board[i][j] = printChar('*');
                    System.out.print("   " + board[i][j]);
                }
                System.out.println();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `printChar('*')`?

Comment: If I may suggest : Wrap your board[][] in a class that represent a Board, this board have some sections, and have a method called print() that prints one '*' per section. It might be easier to write and debug.

Comment: This statement works perfectly `System.out.print('*');`. As @SharonBenAsher asked, what is `printChar(char c)` method. Can you show it?

Comment: you aren't using the `Random rand = new Random();`?

Comment: @Unknown that's what I tried and it gives incompatible error

Comment: @BladeMight under int board I have it

Comment: Now its like walking blind folded. It would be helpful if you show us the exact error/exception occured and the `printChar` method.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be what you're looking for:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class project {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int rows = 0;
    while (rows < 1 || rows > 9) {
        System.out.println("rows? ");
        rows = 8; //sc.nextInt();
    }
    int columns = 0;
    while (columns < 1 || columns > 9) {
        System.out.println("columns? ");
        columns = 8; //sc.nextInt();
        int length = 0;
        System.out.println("side length? ");
        length = 2;//sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("   " + "|");
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            System.out.print("   " + j);
        }
        System.out.println("  |");
        for (int j = 0; j <= columns; j++) {
            System.out.print("----");
        }
        System.out.println("--|");
        boolean[][] board = new boolean[rows][columns];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            System.out.print(i + "  |");
            int secte = i / length;
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                int secti = j / length;
                String aste = " ";
                if (!board[secte][secti]) {
                    Random rand = new Random();
                    if (rand.nextBoolean()) {
                        aste = "*";
                        board[secte][secti] = true;
                    }
                    if (j == columns) {
                        aste = "*";
                        board[secte][secti] = true;
                    }
                }
                System.out.print("   " + aste);
            }
            System.out.println("  |");
        }
    }
}
}
```

I modified your code to fixed rows:8, columns:8, length:2(I used it as section's length by 2D), so code outputs:

```
rows?
columns?
side length?
   |   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7  |
--------------------------------------|
0  |       *   *       *       *      |
1  |                                  |
2  |               *   *              |
3  |       *                   *      |
4  |   *           *   *       *      |
5  |                                  |
6  |   *       *       *           *  |
7  |                                  |
```

i.e. every length's sections in rows/columns has only one asterisk.

Comment: it close to what I am looking but the row , col, & side length has to change based on user input. It's not supposed to be set.

Comment: @KimikoMisaki But you can change the code back that i commented, it will work.(the `sc.nextInt()` lines)